# MS Graph Odata filter like SQL where x in (a,b,c)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

Using Graph SDK, i would like to query a list that field x is in any of the values a b or c for example.

In SQL I would have

```
Where x in (a,b,c)
```

I know I can build a string like `$filter = x eq a or x eq b or x eq c` but it is not an elegant solution.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` [$filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) operator.

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail in ('user1@xxx.com', 'user2@xxx.com')
```

[OData in operator](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_in)

Comment: It works for users but not for List items. For "fields/FileLeafRef in ('attachment a.docx', '2154.016_Atlantic Health_CareStation BEV_10.2.20_517049_517099.pdf', '1750.007 Prov-PMMC Ortho Call 2020 FMV Report_09.24.20_516425.pdf', 'Thank You Card Tips_463330.pdf', 'Graphics.pptx', 'SRH ASC and Endo Development Proposal.docx')"  I get error "System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: handleConsultantReplace. Microsoft.Graph.Core: Code: invalidRequest"